# Qual è il significato di "rimettere" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola ho letto:

> La notizia che avevano disperatamente atteso per anni: in Italia l'allora primo ministro tanto poco da loro amato si era dimesso. Era salito al Colle, come si usava dire allora, intendendo per Colle il Quirinale, sede del presidente della Repubblica italiana, *rimettendo* il suo mandato.

Ho cercato il significato del verbo "rimettere" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso di "rimettendo" nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tratta di un termine relativo all'atto di rassegnare le dimissioni, come si evince da quanto si riporta alla voce n°1 del significato di [*dimissione*](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/D/dimissione.shtml):

> 1 (spec. pl.) Atto con cui una persona o un gruppo dirigente **rimette** il mandato che ha avuto, rinuncia a una carica, a un ufficio: *dare, rassegnare le d.*

Più precisamente, il termine assume una particolare connotazione nell'ambito giuridico, come riporta il [vocabolario](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rimettere/) *Treccani* (6,b):

> b. Nel linguaggio giur. e amministr., demandare o trasmettere ad altro giudice, organo, ufficio o ente: *r. una causa penale ad altro giudice per legittimo sospetto, r. una causa civile al giudice competente, dopo l’istruttoria* (v. rimessione); *r. un caso alla Corte costituzionale, al Ministro*.

Answer (score 7):

Il verbo *rimettere* viene dal latino *remitto* che significa “mandare indietro”, “restituire”.

Il Presidente della Repubblica nomina il Presidente del Consiglio dei Ministri, dandogli mandato di formare il governo. Se questi rinuncia, rimette quel mandato, cioè lo restituisce a chi gliel'aveva dato.

Come spesso accade, il linguaggio giuridico tende a mantenere il significato originale della parola latina.